# MS access after DB check form wont open

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a access DB and at startup I want to check if the link DB is avalible so I did
the following:

```
cDBPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim Relink_Tables
Dim rsCheckLink As Recordset
Relink_Tables = False

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
     If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
        'Linked table - test link is current
            DoCmd.Echo False, "Checking link for table " & tdf.Name
            On Error Resume Next 'Do not stop script on error
            Set rsCheckLink = db.OpenRecordset(tdf.Name) ' OPEN TABLE
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then ' COULD NOT OPEN TABLE
                On Error GoTo 0
                Relink_Tables = True
                'GoTo Relink_Tables ' RECONNECT TO APPROPIATE DATABASE
            Else
                On Error GoTo 0
                rsCheckLink.Close ' CLOSE TABLE THAT DID OPEN
                Set rsCheckLink = Nothing
            End If
    End If
Next

If Relink_Tables = True Then
   Reling_DB...
End If
```

that part works just fine, the problem is that after that I try to open my main form like: `DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm"`, but it wont open (if I opened the DB by double-clicking the file) nly if I close the DB from the Access's main menu and then re-open it from the 'recent files list' then it will work properly why is that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the form does open, but it doesn't show, because of this line:

```
DoCmd.Echo False, "Checking link for table " & tdf.Name
```

If you turn screen output off, you must be 100% sure that your code works, and that you turn it back on under all circumstances (including error cases).

Actually I don't see a reason to turn Echo off here at all.

To show a status message, and turn the hourglass cursor on, I have a function like this in a public module:

```
' Show (strStatus <> "") or remove (strStatus = "") a statusbar message
Public Sub StatusMsg(strStatus As String, Optional bHourglass As Boolean = False)

    On Error Resume Next

    If strStatus = "" Then
        SysCmd acSysCmdClearStatus
    Else
        SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, strStatus
    End If

    DoCmd.Hourglass bHourglass
    DoEvents

End Sub
```

and call it like

```
StatusMsg "Doing some lengthy stuff", True
' some lengthy stuff here
StatusMsg "", False
```